# Running Squid as an aggregating proxy

Tags: proxy, squid

We've hired a lot of proxies from different providers which are used by our apps. This list gets changed sometimes (once in 2-3 months). To make our life easier we want to configure an aggregating proxy which have to use the hired proxies and balance requests.

The questions are:

- is this possible to use Squid for this? Any other solutions if no?
- provide the config sample please

Comment: It should be possible, just use several `cache_peer`, combined with `cache_peer_access` to create some acls to control which peer to use for based on criteria.  I have no examples though.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, you can use squid for this purpose. Have a look at the **cache_peer** directive. You can even make squid load-balance between multiple parent proxies:

```
cache_peer parent1.foo.net parent 3128 0 round-robin no-query
cache_peer parent2.foo.com parent 3128 0 round-robin no-query
...
```

3128 in this example is the port of the parent proxy to connect to. 0 would be the ICP port but I assume you don't have that kind of close relationship with the proxy parents so it can be set to 0.

See the online documentation, especially [the section about cache_peer](http://www.squid-cache.org/Doc/config/cache_peer/) for more information.

Comment: And what if my proxies require base http authentication?

Comment: Check the documentation of the cache_peer directive. There is an entire section of authentication options via the "login" option. You can specify a username/password combination, you can choose to passthrough the credentials given by the browser, etc. etc. Something like "cache_peer parent1.foo.net parent 3128 0 round-robin no-query login=username:password" should work fine.